# Constant Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I am trying to sum up data in 3 columns one by one and paste the total in next sheet in three cells. I have come up with the following code. It works fine a couple of times but then starts throwing the error: Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Sub test1()

Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 1

For i = 1 To 3

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, i).Value = ""

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(Counter, i)).Select
    Counter = Counter + 1

Loop

    Value1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i).Value = Value1

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried any debugging with break points or `On Error Goto` to see on which line the error is occurring?

Comment: Works fine for me - although I'm struggling to see what you are trying to achieve. As a tip you should include "Option Explicit" at the beginning of your code module, and declare the variables that you are using - e.g. in this case you declared counter but forgot Value1 and i. Not sure where the 1004 should come from, though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select a range in a sheet that is not active, that is what is causing the error.

If you have any sheet besides `Sheet1` active, your code will throw the error you listed.
As a quick fix add `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate` before your loop.

As a better fix, you should try to get select out of your code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!! It helped. I have another problem though. In the same code it is summing up only until column 2. The For loop does not seem to go beyond column 2 even when i = 1 To 3. Thanks in advance,

Comment: It actually does, but I can guess what the issue is... Since you never reset the value of Counter for the next i it continues with the last value. To fix that, move `Counter = 1` to the beginning of your `For` loop.